# which version of jmeter-plugins (>=0.3.0) can work under JDK 1.5?

Tags: tools, java, jmeter

Which version of [jmeter-plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) (version >= 0.3.0) can work under JDK 1.5?
And which version of JMeter is compatible with this version of jmeter-plugins?

Answer (score 1):

All version of JMeter are compatible with JDK 1.5. If you find difficulty to run JMeter, you need to set system variable `Java_Path` in environment variables.

Comment: Question is not about compatibility of Jmeter itself with JDK but about compatibility of package of custom Jmeter plugins - jmeter-plugins (http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) - with JDK under which jmeter is running.